# Make a line move from (0,0) to any angle

Tags: css, css-animations

I've created a line, which appears from 0 to full length on mouse hover. In this code, the line moves from left to right. I just want to make it move from (0,0) to any given angle. Is there any way I can achieve this?

```css
.cspaceintro .intro-container .line2 {
  position: relative;
  left: 890px;
  bottom: 25px;
  width: 2%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #3ebbff;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%，from(#7BC3FF), to(#7BC3FF));
  -webkit-animation: aaa 2s linear 1;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@keyframes aaa {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  30% {
    width: 2%;
  }
  60% {
    width: 4%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 5%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="cspaceintro">
  <div class="intro-container">
    <div id="li2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your code you use class `.line2`, but have HTML of `<div id="li2">`. Did you mean to use `#li2`, or is the `line2` class dynamically generated through JavaScript?

Comment: @ObsidianAge yeah,I have another jquery file to addClass to this element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS3 properties transform and transform-origin.

```
.cspaceintro {
  /* rotate to the respective degrees */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);

  /* sets the origin point for the transformed element */
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0;
  transform-origin: 0;
}
```

Please refer the link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transform?v=example#Live_example